Inequality involving matrix trace and diagonalisable matrices
Given two real PSD matrices diagonalisable by orthogonal matrices: $A=UDU^T$ and $B=VEV^T$, prove that
$$tr(A+B-2(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^{1/2})\geq0.$$
We can rewrite the inequality as
$$tr(D)+tr(E)\geq tr((UD^{1/2}U^TVEV^TUD^{1/2}U^T)^{1/2}).$$
Now, the RHS becomes
$$tr(U(D^{1/2}U^TVEV^TUD^{1/2})^{1/2}U^T)=tr((D^{1/2}U^TVEV^TUD^{1/2})^{1/2}),$$
but I am not sure how to rigorously compute the remaining square root.

are they also PSD? otherwise, how do you define the square root?

with $X:= B^\frac{1}{2}A^\frac{1}{2}$ then $\text{trace}\big((A^\frac{1}{2}BA^\frac{1}{2})^\frac{1}{2}\big) =\big\Vert X \big\Vert_{S_1}=\big\Vert X \big\Vert_{*}$ and this is essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3512008/prove-that-x-min-a-b-x-a-f-b-f-min-a-b-x/

Suppose $A,B$ are PSD, otherwise it is unclear how you can take the square root.
Call $F = (D^{1/2}U^TVEV^TUD^{1/2})^{1/2}$ and $C = \sqrt D\ge 0$ diagonal. You have to prove
$$Tr(C^2) + Tr(C^{-1}F^2 C^{-1}) \ge 2 Tr(F)  $$
but this holds for every element on the diagonal, since
$$C_{i,i}^2 + \frac{(F^2)_{i,i}}{C_{i,i}^2}\ge 2 \sqrt {(F^2)_{i,i}} = 2 \sqrt{\sum_j F_{i,j}^2} \ge 2 F_{i,i}  $$

If $D$ is singular, call $\tilde D$  the restriction to the principal square submatrix with rows and columns corresponding to the nonzero entries of $D$. Call $\tilde G$ the restriction of $U^TVEV^TU$ to the same submatrix. $E$ is SPD, so the diagonal elements of $U^TVEV^TU$ are nonnegative, and thus
$$ tr(D)+tr(E)\geq tr(\tilde D)+tr(\tilde G),\qquad  tr((D^{1/2}U^TVEV^TUD^{1/2})^{1/2}) = tr((\tilde D^{1/2}\tilde G \tilde D^{1/2})^{1/2}) $$
where now $\tilde D$ is invertible, so we can use the solution above.

Do you need to add something addressing the case that $A, B$ are both singular ($C, D$ is not invertible)?

if $D$ has some zero on the diagonal, you can restrict to the square submatrix relative to the nonzero diagonal elements of $D$

Do you think it is trivial, or you need to address them?

it's very trivial

OK. Although it is easy, but since you decide not to include something addressing this case in the answer, that's fine.

@RiverLi added an explanation

Nice. Thanks for editing.

Let $X=A^{1/2}$ and $Y=B^{1/2}$. Perform a polar decomposition of $XY=PU$, where $P$ is PSD and $U$ is orthogonal. Then
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{tr}\left(A+B-2(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^{1/2}\right)
&=\operatorname{tr}(X^2+Y^2-2P)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(X^2+Y^2-XYU^T-UYX)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(X^2+Y^2-YU^TX-XUY)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left((X-YU^T)(X-UY)\right)\\
&=\|X-UY\|_F^2\ge0.
\end{align*}

with $\lambda_1\geq \lambda_2\geq\dots\geq \lambda_n$ and $\sigma_1\geq \sigma_2\geq\dots\geq \sigma_n$ denoting the respective singular values (i.e. eigenvalues) of $A^\frac{1}{2}$ and $B^\frac{1}{2}$, and well chosen $Q\in O_n\big(\mathbb R\big)$
$$\begin{aligned}\text{trace}\big((A^\frac{1}{2}BA^\frac{1}{2})^\frac{1}{2}\big) &=\big\Vert B^\frac{1}{2}A^\frac{1}{2}\big\Vert_{S_1}\\ &=\text{trace}\big((QB^\frac{1}{2})A^\frac{1}{2}\big)\\ &\leq\sum_{k=1}^n (\lambda_k^2\sigma_k^2)^\frac{1}{2}\\ &\leq  \frac{1}{2}\cdot \Big( \big(\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k^2\big)+\big(\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k^2\big)\Big)\\&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\text{trace}\Big(A +B\Big) \end{aligned}$$
where $S_1$ indicates the Schatten 1 norm (sum of singular values) and the inequalities are the von-Neumann trace inequality and $\text{GM}\leq \text{AM}$
